Quartz stops triggering jobs after few days of running (ASP.NET Core 8)
I'm trying to find a root cause of problem with jobs execution of .NET  quartz library. I have 4 jobs which run as QuartzHostedService in my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API.
Here's a method which I use to setup each of job:
private static IServiceCollectionQuartzConfigurator AddCronScheduledJob<T>(this IServiceCollectionQuartzConfigurator configure, string cronExpression) where T: IJob
{
        var jobKey = new JobKey(typeof(T).Name);
        configure.AddJob<T>(opts => opts.WithIdentity(jobKey));
        configure.AddTrigger(opts => opts
            .ForJob(jobKey)
            .WithIdentity($"{typeof(T).Name}-trigger")
            .WithCronSchedule(cronExpression).StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(3)));

        return configure;
}

services.AddQuartz(configure =>
        {
            configure.AddCronScheduledJob<Job1>("0 */10 * * * ?");
            configure.AddCronScheduledJob<Job2>("0 */10 * * * ?");
            configure.AddCronScheduledJob<Job3>("0 */30 * * * ?");
            configure.AddCronScheduledJob<Job4>("0 */15 * * * ?");
        });
services.AddQuartzHostedService();
return services;

Everything works fine, until randomly one of configured job does not stop be triggering in scheduled time. Jobs does not have any "infinity" loops or some unhandled exceptions.
Application runs as docker image in kubernetes pod. I'm trying to find any solution which allows me to identify root of that problem or I was wondering, maybe is there a way to "reschedule" jobs again after some time?
